# When I open Google Chrome on an Android emulator, my emulator completely freezes

Tags: android-studio

When I run the emulator on API version 31 and higher, when I launch Google Chrome it completely freezes. For the emulator to work, I need to turn it off completely.

When I try to do the same on API version 30 and below, everything works as expected.

Vulcan is disabled in the emulator settings.
Android Studio version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04, Codename: jammy

I tried disabling the volcano via advanced.ini, tried to give access to the Google Chrome storage, but it didn't help me

Comment: Try another emulator like Genymotion free

Comment: @cmak I want to figure out why something that should work doesn't work